# How to perform strace on shell without changing your current shell?

Tags: zsh, exec, strace

I use `strace` to trace the behavior of a `bash` process. The purpose is to find out the order `bash` loads its configuration files.

I am running the following command under `zsh`:

```bash
strace -e openat bash
```

After running this command, I end up in a new `bash` shell, but I don't want that to happen. Is there any way to trace the `bash` command without actually starting new `bash` interactive shell?

I searched online but couldn't find anything. I was trying this with `exec`: `strace -e openat "$(exec bash)" 2>&1`, but still my shell changes to `bash` from `zsh`.

Comment: You _are_ starting a `bash` shell, so naturally, you will be left inside an interactive `bash` session (note: you do not log in again, only starting another shell session). If you want to exit that shell session, can't you just type `exit`?

Comment: Yes, I can use `Ctrl+d` as well instead of `exit` but was curious if there is a way to trace without leaving `zsh` itself.

Comment: Well, you could stace bash running a non-interactive shell with `strace bash -c 'exit'` or similar, but since you want to investigate how that shell reads its startup files, you'd get a different result as what files are being read by default are different depending on if the shell is started as an interactive, non-interactive or login shell.  This _does_ sound a bit like an X-Y question. What is it you are trying to figure out by doing this? It strikes me that the order in which the shell reads its startup files is documented in the manual.

Comment: Also note that unless you explicitly _replace_ the `zsh` process with `exec`, you are not "leaving" `zsh`.  You are only starting another application (`bash`) and you return to your `zsh` shell when the application has terminated.

Comment: Considering the startup files, also remember that Bash reads a different set of startup files when started as a login shell vs. a non-login shell. But yes, [it's documented in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html), even though the actual rules are somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask `bash` to exit immediately, and force it to behave like an interactive and/or login shell:

```
strace -e openat bash -i -c exit
```

Add `-l` to make `bash` act like an interactive login shell.

Note that this will also show files read when exiting (`.bash_logout` etc.).